# Перенаправление события дочерних элементов c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Такой вопрос. Есть декстоп на windows Form c#. Там есть панельки, на панельках лейблы, другие элементы и т.д. Создал событие, что при наведении мыши панель перекрашивается, но если навести на этой же панели на дочерние элементы(ну лэйбл там внутри этой панели), то окрашивание не работает. Как исправить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11043661/12888024

Comment: Можно в событии выхода проверять координаты мыши, и если они внутри панельки, то не реагировать на событие. Покажите код.

Comment: Да у меня код уже разросся, там и класс новый появился в отдельном файле... Задача то простая, есть элемент panel. Когда на него навожу, он меняет цвет. Но внутри этой панели есть label и если навести конкретно на label, то panel цвет не поменяет. Вот можно ли сделать так, чтобы label стал как то частью панели или может еще как то. А по поводу отслеживать. Если бы эта была 1 панель, то да. Но их будет много.

Comment: Да, ваш ответ сверху мне подошел! Благодарю! А где можно поискать объяснение, не совсем понял как это работает.

Comment: Это обработка сообщения Windows, долгая история. Система окну присылает сообщение, окно рассылает его своим контролам. Этот метод просто всегда отвечает "меня здесь нет" от имени контрола.